# How To Establish A Relation Between An EditText and TextView in Android?

Tags: android

Is there anyway to establish a relationship between an edittext and textview that is inside a table row? The purpose is to change the color of textview while the edittext is clicked. Some kind of parent child relationship is possible? Any clue? Thanks.

Comment: yup it's possible. why don't you search it yourself first :)

Answer (score 1):

You can either use onClickListener or addTextWatcher on Edittext to achieve required behavior.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this, when `EditText` will be in focus `TextView` color will get changed, and on focusing other view color will get changed again.**

```
 editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean isFocused) {
                textView.setTextColor(isFocused ? ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.bg_red) : ContextCompat.getColor(R.color.bg_blue));
            }
        });
```